# Catch an event in a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, events

I was wondering if it was possible to catch an event in another workbook.

A macro will open a workbook for the user to use, and I want to be able to run another macro on its selection_change event. No, the code can't be stored in the just opened workbook.

Is there any other way than programmatically adding a code to the opened workbook's **`ThisWorkbook`** module?

That way is unsafe and unstable and generally bleh.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do it grab a `WithEvents` reference to the opened workbook in a class module with your event handlers.  For example:

```
'In ThisWorkbook 
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents other As Worksheet

Private Sub Example()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Dev\other.xlsx")
    Set other = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

End Sub

Private Sub other_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Debug.Print Target.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't work for me, the other_SelectionChange doesn't fire when I change the selection. I'll keep experimenting tomorrow though, it might just be too late for me now...

Comment: Such a code seems to work only after the class is instantiated and until the "Reset" VBA button is pressed.