# Can a saved/closed workbook recognize events from an open wb that contains no code?

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario:  FileA, containing no VBA, is exported to Excel weekly from an outside DB.  I'd like the user to 'Save As' this file to an already existing FileB (whose location and file name don't change).  The FileA Save As action would trigger code in FileB to open, manipulate data in FileA, copy data to FileB, save it as FileB (overwriting prior content - but retaining code), and discard FileA.

I've worked through the code to manipulate the data, transfer it, save/close, etc.  Where I'm stumped is having the "SaveAs" action in FileA act as the trigger for action in FileB.

Can a `WithEvents` reference to the opened workbook in a class module help solve this?

Comment: Where did you read this about `WithEvents`?

Comment: Always happy to be proven wrong but... :-)   The way you describe it just will not work.  FileB is dead.  Deceased.  Has no awareness at all :-).  It cannot respond to being overwritten.  Using SaveAS from FileA will just overwrite FileB. However... assuming you can't change the content of FileA (created externally) - why not do it the other way around?   User opens FileB, clicks a button and code in file B opens FileA, copies data from FileA into FileB, saves itself (FileB) and then deletes FileA.

Comment: "WithEvents" is something different (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz(v=vs.90).aspx).  That's where an application 'listens' for something and then reacts.  And for that to happen, FileB would need to be open with code running in the first place.   I'm sure it's not implemented in VBA,  only VB/VB.Net.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett:   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832271/catch-an-event-in-a-different-workbook/30833710#30833710) is reference about WithEvents

Comment: @EyePeaSea - Thanx for confirming my fears. WithEvents is implemented in VBA (I see it used for referencing imbedded charts & for userforms). I was holding out hope that a closed file would be able to 'listen' for an event from an open one. Alas, not. Your alternative it is.