# Can Excel VBA in one workbook detect when another WB (VBA) writes to a 3rd Co-authored WB?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a redundant application process wherein a secondary WB (.XLSM) takes over performing an operation if it detects the primary XLSM WB hasn't changed a 'flag' cell. That cell's in a 3rd co-authored WB (XLSX - no VBA code.

I've tried a dozen mechanisms - DoEvent loops, OnTime subs, etc (to release the processor), in both Primary & secondary WBs with scattered results. I've also played with 'Sharing' the 3rd WB and Co-authoring it. The closest I can come to it working is when the Writing WB closes its access to the 3rd WB. I can't be the first to try such a scheme, but I find nothing online that has successfully given a solution.

Has anyone created a real-time redundant system with Excel 365 VBA?

I've generated so much code that failed that I thought it easier to explain the target. Also, there are 2 WBs each with their own code. The 3rd WB is loosely a data file that's updated daily. I could change the architecture with an attempt to drop in Access, but I can't get approval for that.

Comment: "detects the primary XLSM WB hasn't changed a 'flag' cell" - you can read that cell at any time from XLSM#2.  However in the scenario you want to detect there's no event to capture (nothing was done), so likely the best you could do is use something like `Application.OnTime` in a loop inside XLSM#2 to check whether XLSM#1 did its job or not.  It's not clear on how you'd know at what point it had failed though.

Comment: Note you *can* capture an event in another workbook, if you can figure out what event might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832271/catch-an-event-in-a-different-workbook

Comment: Tim,
Appreciate the response. You seem to grasp the issue. I run a loop with OnTime & check for changes each loop. The 'fail' time (# loops) is arbitrary. BAD news - the secondary ALWAYS times out. My theory is both Pri & Sec are using copies of the real file - no common data until sync'ed. If I'm right, that obviates "real time" interaction. With Co-authoring changes by multiple people are visible in real time, but VBA-based simulations aren't. Hence my curiosity whether any minds greater than mine had conquered such a challenge in an MS Office environment. :-(

Comment: I've never dealt with that scenario.